# Lambda capture causes incompatible operand types error?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, clang

Consider the following code:

```
main()
{
    bool t;
    ...
    std::function<bool (bool)> f = t ? [](bool b) { return b; } : [](bool b) { return !b; }; // OK
    std::function<bool (bool)> f = t ? [t](bool b) { return t == b; } : [t](bool b) { return t != b; }; // error
}
```

When compiled with Clang 3.1, the assignment of non-capture lambda works while the one with captures fails:

```
main.cpp:12:36: error: incompatible operand types ('<lambda at main.cpp:12:38>' and '<lambda at main.cpp:12:71>')
        std::function<bool (bool)> f2 = t ? [t](bool b) { return t == b; } : [t](bool b) { return t != b; }; // error
                                          ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why does capturing the same variable causes the 2 lambdas to be of incompatible types?

Comment: I don't understand what I need to do so that it actually compiles...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The type of a lambda is "a unique, non-union class type" called the closure type. Each lambda is implemented as a different type, local to the scope of declaration, which has an overloaded operator () to call the function body.

**Example**: if you write this:

```
auto a=[t](bool b){return t==b;};
auto b=[t](bool b){return t!=b;};
```

Then the compiler compiles this (more or less):

```
class unique_lambda_name_1 
{
 bool t; 
public:
 unique_lambda_name_1(bool t_) t(_t) {}
 bool operator () (bool b) const { return t==b; }
} a(t); 
class unique_lambda_name_2
{
 bool t;
public: 
 unique_lambda_name_2(bool t_) t(_t) {}
 bool operator () (bool b) const { return t!=b; }
} b(t);
```

a and b have different types and can't be used in the ?: operator.

However, §5.1.2(6) says, that the closure type of a lambda with no capture has a non-explicit, public conversion operator, which converts the lambda to a function pointer - non-closures can be implemented as simple functions. Any lambda with the same argument and return types can be converted to the same type of pointer and so the ternary ?: operator can be applied to them.

**Example:** the non-capture lambda:

```
auto c=[](bool b){return b;};
```

is implemented like this:

```
class unique_lambda_name_3
{
 static bool body(bool b) { return b; }
 public:
 bool operator () (bool b) const { return body(b); }
 operator decltype(&body) () const { return &body; }
} c;
```

which means that this line:

```
auto x = t?[](bool b){return b;}:[](bool b){return !b;};
```

means actually this:

```
// a typedef to make this more readable
typedef bool (*pfun_t)(bool); 
pfun_t x = t?((pfun_t)[](bool b){return b;}):(pfun_t)([](bool b){return !b;});
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I didn't know they are implemented differently. It makes sense now.