# Return lambda from ternary operator

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I can return a lambda from ternary operator if both the lambda doesn't capture anything.

```
 auto lambda1 = 1==1
             ? [] (int a) {std::cout << "First\n";}
             : [] (int a) {std::cout << "Second\n";};

 auto lambda2 = 1==2
             ? [] (int a) {std::cout << "First\n";}
             : [] (int a) {std::cout << "Second\n";};
lambda1(10);
lambda2(10);
```

This works fine.

But this doesn't

```
int n = 10;

auto lambda3 = 1==1
             ? [&n] (int a) {std::cout << "First\n";}
             : [&n] (int a) {std::cout << "Second\n";};

 auto lambda4 = 1==2
             ? [&n] (int a) {std::cout << "First\n";}
             : [&n] (int a) {std::cout << "Second\n";};
lambda3(10);
lambda4(10);
```

The error is `main.cpp:20:18: error: operands to ?: have different types 'main()::<lambda(int)>' and 'main()::<lambda(int)>' ? [&n] (int a) {std::cout << "First\n";}`

I wonder why capturing the same variable changes the type of lambda?

Comment: See explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/11406936/8769985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **8.4.5.1 Closure types [expr.prim.lambda.closure]**
>
> 1. **The type** of a lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a **unique**  unnamed non-union class type, called the closure type.

So `lambda3` and `lambda4` having capture are unique types which are different from each other.

> 7. The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression **with no lambda-capture** whose constraints (if any) are satisﬁed has a conversion function to **pointer to function** with C++ language linkage having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function call operator.

`lambda1` and `lambda2` (having no capture) can be converted to pointer to function and are of the same type.